# Change the value in a dropdownlist

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Using VS 2013 (VB) with sql server 2012.

I have a drop down list that populates with values from a DB table using datacontext.  Code below

```
        With ddlHedgesCompanies
        .DataSource = DB.GasCompanies
        .DataValueField = "ID"
        .DataTextField = "CompanyName"
        .DataBind()
    End With
```

I want to adjust the value of one of the values as it doesn't display how I want.  I though I could do it with an if statement but cant seem to access the value.

The item I want to change is FirstName to First Name.

I am assuming this is easy to do I just cant see it.

Comment: why not adjust the value before you populate?

Comment: I cant as far as I know as using the .datatextfield="companyName" just pulls all the entries for company name from the DB

Comment: i am not sure right now if you can change values if they are bound. So i would retrieve the values from DB change the values you want to change and load it into a list and bind the list to the Dropdownlist

Comment: You could use the OnDataBound event of the dropdownlist which fires once the ddl is databound and then go through each of the values and change the one(s) you need to.

Comment: It would be more efficient to modify your query get you the data in the format you want. Iterating through each record on databind would be slower.